# Python and PYODBC. I'm unable to read results to a proper dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pyodbc

I seem to be unable to read the results to a dictionary. It keeps giving me the results as a list, not a dictionary.

Here is my code:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()    

# Sample select query
cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 500 [OrderNumber], [ProductID] FROM [dbo].[Results]")    

columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]    

results = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]    

for x in results.values():
    print(x)
```

It's giving me a list, not a dictionary. Here's what I am getting instead:

```
[{'OrderNumber': '123456789', 'ProductID': '11111111'}, {'OrderNumber': '234567891', 'ProductID': '222222'}
```

It's not a dictionary as I need it to be. I tried reading it like a dictionary and Python keeps telling me that I'm looking at a list. Looking at values() or items(), it's giving me an error that the list object has no attribute 'values' `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'`

Moreover, how can I get my results to be the actual order number to be the key of the productID? Something like:

```
{"123456789":"11111111", "234567891":"22222222"}
```

I did try other methods of getting this, and I'm still getting a list, not an actual dictionary. I tried:

```
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        results.append(dict(zip(columns,row)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning `results` as a new list because you're using a list comprehension. You should try using something like a dict comprehension instead, or even just create a dict manually using a for loop:

```
results = {k:v for (row[columns.index('OrderNumber')], row[columns.index('ProductID')]) in cursor.fetchall()}
```

or more simply: (sicnce we already know each of these columns have these indexes

```
 results = {k:v for (row[0], row[1]) in cursor.fetchall()}
```

this would be the same as running:

```
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description] 
results = {} 
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    results[row[0]] = row[1]  # short version
    # or use this instead if you have a lot of columns and don't remember index
    results[row[columns.index('OrderNumber')]] = row[columns.index('ProductID')]
```